# Tab Bar Controller index changing?

Tags: swift, indexing, uitabbarcontroller

I have 2 tabs : Calc VC and Browse VC; they are in that order and the app starts on Calc VC.

Using a print statement tabbarcontroller.selectedindex in viewwillappear of each VCs I learned that when Calc VC first appear, it shows an index of 0. When I tap on Browse VC, it shows an index of 1. So far so good.

When I tap on Calc VC, its index becomes 1 and Browse VC becomes 0. It remains like that until you quit the app.

Why it's an issue? I'm trying to disable Browse VC when Calc VC is active by using .isEnabled = false but I can't do it that way because of the changing index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of `viewWillAppear` triggered, selectedIndex might not be changed. You should use `viewDidAppear`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   print(tabBarController?.selectedIndex)
}
```

Or you can use [tabBar(_:didSelect:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbardelegate/1623463-tabbar) of `UITabBarDelegate`

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
   print(tabBar.items?.index(of: item))
}
```